# How can I stop the MPMoviePlayer from automatically starting the streaming video in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayer

I encounter the some problems while trying to play the streaming movie in Mpmovieplayer. I want to prepare for streaming movie to be ready inside the load method and then start it after clicking the button(toggle play method). But sometimes it plays automatically before clicking the button. (about 20%). I don't know how to figure it out.

```
 func load(~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~){
 self.doPause()
    self.isOnMetaData = false
    self.isLive = isLivePlay
    self.playURL = path
    self.isFile = isFile
    self.isAutoPlay = isAutoPlay
    if(isFile==false && isAutoPlay==true){
        if(self.checkNetworkAllow()==false){

            return false
        }
    }
    if(isAutoPlay == true){
        self.loadBar?.startAnimating()
    }else{
        self.loadBar?.stopAnimating()
    }

    self.isPlaying=false
    self.resetPlayerStatus()
    self.setActive(true)
    PlayerManager.instance!.setActivePlayer(self)

    if(self.isLive == true){
        self.uiSeekBox?.hidden = true
    }else{
        self.uiSeekBox?.hidden = false
    }
    print("play path : " +  path)


    if(isFile == true){
        self.player!.contentURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    }else{
        self.player!.contentURL = NSURL(string: path)
    }

    let isUrl:Bool = (playURL?.containsString("bora"))!   //icesky86 add

    }
     self.player!.shouldAutoplay = false
     self.isBora = true
     self.player!.prepareToPlay()
}
```

->> Load Method Part

```
func togglePlay(){


    if(self.isPlaying == false){
        if(self.isBora == true){

            let second = 0.9
            let delay = second * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
            let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
            dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.loadBar!.hidden = true
            })
        }

        self.play()

    }else{
        self.pause()  
    }

}
```

Please help me .

Comment: Try to Pause the player just after `prepareToPlay`.

Comment: I attach the player.pause. But it doesn't work